# Choice of particular solution to this second order, inhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to solve this second order linear inhomogeneous ODE:
$$
y''+2y'+5y=xe^x.
$$

And I'm a bit confused what choice to take as my particular solution $y_p.$ I see that the solution to the corresponding homogeneous equation is $y_h(x):= e^{-x}(a cos (x) + b sin (x)).$ Based on this and following the table in [this link](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/17%3A_Second-Order_Differential_Equations/17.2%3A_Nonhomogeneous_Linear_Equations), I tried taking forst:

$$y_p(x):= Axe^x,$$

which led me to this:

$$Ae^x(x+2) + 2Ae^x(x+1) + 5Axe^x = xe^x,$$

which clearly cannot be solved for $A.$

So the next things I want to try is:

$$y_p(x):= xe^x(A cos(x) + B sin (x))$$

and then solve for both $A,B.$ But I'm not intuitively clear why I need two unknown constants $A,B$ instead of just one, namely $A$ which failed.

**My questions are:**
(1) Is $y_p(x):= xe^x(A cos(x) + B sin (x))$ a correct choice for the particular solution $y_p?$

(2) If not what's the correct choice and why (with some intuition)?

Thanks in advance and relevant links apppreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you try $y_p(x) = (A+Bx)e^x$,
$$
2Be^x+(A+Bx)e^x + 2Be^x + 2(A+Bx)e^x + 5(A+Bx)e^x = xe^x \Rightarrow A = -\frac{1}{16}, B= \frac{1}{8}.
$$
So,
$$
\boxed{y_p(x)=-\frac{1}{16}\left(1-2x\right)e^x.}
$$